# ¿como enviar un String a un metodo?

Tags: java

Hola bueno empece a ver java en la universidad y estamos viendo archivos y nos dieron a probar un metodo al cual solo le debemos de enviar un String que va a ser el nombre con el que se guardara el archivo en si es facil pero me marca un error, el metodo es el siguiente

```
public static String [] cargarArreglo (String archivo) throws IOException {

    // primero se lee el archivo para contar el número de líneas

         FileReader a = new FileReader (archivo);

         BufferedReader dentro = new BufferedReader (a);

         int n = 0;

         String linea = dentro.readLine ();

         while (linea != null) {

               linea = dentro.readLine ();

               n++;

          }
         a.close ();

        // Creación del arreglo

        String [] v = new String [n];

        // Ciclo para leer las cadenas del archivo en el arreglo

        a = new FileReader (archivo);

        dentro = new BufferedReader (a);

        int i = 0;

        linea = dentro.readLine ();

        while ((linea != null) && (i <n)) {

           v [i] = linea;

           linea = dentro.readLine ();

           i++;

         }

         a.close ();

         return v;

      }
```

Ese es el metodo, asi que lo que hice fue hacer el main en la misma clase ya que el metodo es estatico e hice esto

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String archivo1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingresa el nombre del archivo");
    cargarArreglo(archivo1);
}
```

pero al ejecutarlo me sale este error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: archivo (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at nombrearchivo.cargarArreglo(nombrearchivo.java:14)
at nombrearchivo.main(nombrearchivo.java:64)
```

En la parte  Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: archivo (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado) "archivo" es la cadena que se guarda en la variable para despues enviarla al metodo

¿Como puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: Quieres crear un archivo, o el parámetro que recibe el método es para leer un archivo?

Comment: el parametro es para leer el archivo pero lo nombro igual que al archivo que cree, pero me aparece ese error, supongo que es por que no lo guardo en el lugar correcto para que el programa lo lea, uso eclipse pero no se donde guardarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes no es porque estés pasando incorrectamente el `String` al método `cargarArreglo()`, sino, que ese `String` debe contener la ruta (ej. en Windows: D:\carpetaX\archivo.txt) del archivo que deseas cargar, y no solo el nombre (ej. archivo.txt). Por este motivo es que no se encuentra el archivo y se lanza la excepción.

Para solucionarlo te recomiendo que utilices la clase `JFileChooser` que te permite mostrar una ventana de selección de archivos. De modo evitas ese tipo de problemas.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    cargarArreglo(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: El problema es que el programa no se ejecuta debido al error al enviar el string y ya que no se ejecuta, no se crea el archivo asi que no puedo buscarlo, el objetivo del programa es crear y guardar un archivo con el nombre que se ingrese

Comment: Pero es que tú código no crea un archivo, lo lee.

Comment: Tienes la razon amigo, perdon yo me confundi con el programa, muchas gracias, ademas gracias por enseñarme esa funcion